# Breadcrumbs are not clickable in Google search results

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs, json-ld

I have added breadcrumb in my html file and google has indexed it.
But I couldn't click the items listed in the breadcrumb.
Is there any fix to do to make them clickable?
Also is it possible to make links appear in Google search results?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about how Google shows the breadcrumbs in the search results. Then they are not clickable. They are for information only.

By links I suspect you are talking about site links under a specific result. These are automatically worked out by Google. Typically they include pages high up in your navigational structure, like an about us page.